# Mixing reference and value behavior in operator[]

Tags: c++

I need "double" behavior from `operator[]`, sometimes it must return a new instance variable (aka "temporary") and sometimes a reference to another variable so that `=` assignment can be used on the result.

```
var &getItemAt(int i) {}
var &operator[] (int i) {
    if (this->isArray()) {
        return getItemAt(i);
    }
    var result = "undefined";
    return result; <-- Error: attempt to return a reference to a local variable
}

var a = 123; // var can be a number, array, string or 'undefined'
var b;
b.setType("array");
b.push("one", "two", "three");
b[1] = "new value"; // needs to be var& for the assignment to work
```

If I attempt to declare like this (without &):

```
var operator[] (int i) {
```

the assignment to `b[1] = ...` will do nothing (in fact it will assign to a temporary variable, which is a copy of the one from the array found at index position 1 and holding the value "two".

But if I declare `var & operator =` the array semantics works perfectly, but I cannot return `undefined` or other temporary var.

How to mix both behavior into one?

Comment: FWIW, this is not a good idea at all, IMHO. It's the kind of stuff C people point out when they say that in C++ you have no idea what is doing what. These operators have conventions, and if you need something else, I'd make it explicit. Having said that, good luck with your question.

Comment: You have to make `operator[]` return a class which then has `operator=` and conversion operator defined on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few solutions, althought 'static' will work for some cases, if you want to write to the returned newly created object, you will need to garbage collect it later. So the 'undefined' variable is allocated, rooted in the GC and then freed by the GC during it's memory deallocation turn.

You can also declare a wrapper class that would represent both data or a reference when needed and return that from the funtion, but then again you need to think how the allocated data shall bee freed, may be by reference counting.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a reference to a static variable:

```
var &operator[] (int i) {
    if (this->isArray()) {
        return getItemAt(i);
    }
    static var result = "undefined";
    return result;
}
```

This variable will exist until program termination, so won't dangle.

This is exactly the kind of thing that [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) and [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) aim to address.

Comment: what if the returned value is being write accessed?

Comment: You could also try `var *result = new std::string("undefined");` but you'll have to remember to delete it at some point.

Comment: Then it will silently succeed. If you want different behaviour, you could write a wrapper which throws an exception if you try to modify the static instance, or use one of the `optional` implementations I mentioned.